# Looking for PHP Session data in Redis

Tags: php, session, redis

I have changed PHP session handler to Redis. Calling `session_start()` does not throw any exception. Checking `phpinfo()` also tells me everything is OK. Also, more importantly, the session is working fine. But there is something I wish to know:

How should I find the php session data (key) in Redis? I mean, using `redis-cli get {keyName}`, what is the `keyName` for php sessions?

Comment: just flush all and execute `keys *` to see all the keys. It could be something like `PHPREDIS_SESSION:j9rsgtde6st2rqb6lu5u6f4h83`

Comment: The keyname is likely to be whatever the value of the session id is, but we can't tell you for certain because we don't know what's in the session manager that you've written to change your session handling

Comment: Found it. The key name for my server is PHPREDIS_SESSION{a random token}